# How to save integer alongside of a np.array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, machine-learning

I am doing a ConvNet and need to save one image alongside an integer (1 or 0), that indicates if an action was taken or not. How can I do it? I tried this:

```
key_pressed = np.array(key_check(self.key)) # key_check() returns 1 or 0
window = np.array(window) # window is opened with cv2

print(window.shape, key_pressed.shape) # (474, 31) (1,)
print(np.concatenate((window, key_pressed)))
      ^^
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Is doing what I want even possible with numpy, seeing that the arrays are of different sizes? Any ideas on how to save this data?

Comment: can't you put the key pressed as an extension of the filename where you save your image? `np.save("myimage_%f" % key_pressed, window)`

Comment: Its inside a while loop, I am capturing a video

Comment: Ok, but how does that prevent from using `np.save("myimage_%f" % key_pressed, window)` ?

Comment: Consider using `pickle` to save a list of this number and array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy won't let you simply concatenate things of arbitrary sizes: that breaks the functional definition of an array or matrix.  You're trying to make a simple juxtaposition, not a functional concatenation.  All you're trying to do is display them side by side, right?  This isn't a matrix operation.  For instance, do you really envision doing a matrix multiplication on the resulting glued array???

You need a simple container to hold both items.  I expect that a trivial `class` will do the job for you.  Write a combined display method for the resulting pair, and use that for your rendering.

Comment: Would be saving it as a list (key_pressed, window) too bad? I'm afraid the program will use too much ram if the data is too big. I also don't want to save to a .txt file as it's too easy to modify, that is why I am trying to use .npy, but is there some easier/better file choice?

Comment: The tuple would be just fine.  I don't know what file choices might work for you, since "capturing a video" is a very generic application.  You might want to save the tuples as a file of generic objects.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `scipy.io.savemat` and `loadmat`:

```
savemat(your_path, dict(key=key_pressed, window=window))
```

Then using `loadmat` you'll get back a dict with the key and the frame that you want.
There is even a `do_compression` parameter.

Edit: the incompatibility in shapes have nothing to do with it, since you're not creating a new array but saving key and window separately in the same file.

```
In [53]: from scipy import io

In [54]: a = np.zeros([3, 4])

In [55]: b = np.ones([5, 17])

In [56]: io.savemat("foo.mat", dict(a=a, b=b))
```

it works like a charm.

Comment: I think scipy uses numpy to save too, as it gives the exact same error

Comment: No, the error must come from another place. Try my sample code, you'll see that it works.

Comment: @Setti did you do really try `savemat(your_path, dict(key=key_pressed, window=window))` ?